# Removing turmeric stains from white plastic

Tags: spices, cleaning, tumeric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove turmeric stains from metal/plastic cookware?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15162/how-do-i-remove-turmeric-stains-from-metal-plastic-cookware)

I had tried detergents to remove some light turmeric strains off a plastic but after it failed then someone told me to keep the plastic affected with turmeric strains under sun rays in the afternoon. So, I kept it for 15 minutes and the strains were just vanished! How did it work?

Answer (score 3):

The sun's UV radiation breaks up the dye (color) molecules that have stained your plastic. As the bonds in these molecules break down the color starts to fade and eventually may disappear.

This is why some plastics, paper, and other items with color fade over time when exposed to a lot of sunlight.

Comment: Fascinating! I had no idea.